# Laravel Multiple module using one Controller

Tags: laravel-5

Now I have few modules created like Product, Sale, Category. I found out they actually using same function with similar process. For example update() in Controller :

Category

```
public function update($id)
{
        $instance = Category::findOrFail($id);

        $instance->fill(Input::all())->save();
}
```

Product

```
public function update($id)
{
        $instance = Product::findOrFail($id);

        $instance->fill(Input::all())->save();
}
```

How can I join it together to BaseController by just make the Model dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
abstract class ResourceController extends BaseController
{
    protected $entity;

    public function __construct(Model $entity){ //or Eloquent, depending on your import alias

        $this->entity = $entity;
    }


    public function update($id)
    {
        $instance = $this->entity->findOrFail( $id );

        $instance->fill( Input::all() )->save();
    }

}



class ProductController extends ResourceController{
    public function __construct(Product $entity){
        parent::__construct($entity);
    }
}

class CategoryController extends ResourceController{
    public function __construct(Category $entity){
        parent::__construct($entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I get error "Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable."

Comment: I guess that's because you're not overwriting the constructor - you have to do that. So in every Controller that you extend ResourceController with, you have to overwrite the constructor.